# Can't make the function true when the argument is passed JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Problem is simple. When the `scoring` variable is higher than 10, I can't make the `sprawdzRyzyko()` function return boolean true.

```
var high_ryzyko_kraj = ['Polska', 'Afganistan', 'Ukraina'];
var less_ryzyko_kraj = ['Serbia', 'Egipt'];


var scoring = 0;
$('#country, #country-bd, #country-wd').change(function(){
    caunt = $(this).val();
    var arr = $.inArray(caunt, high_ryzyko_kraj);
    var drr = $.inArray(caunt, less_ryzyko_kraj);

    if (arr>-1){  
        scoring += 4 ;
        sprawdzRyzyko();
    }else if(drr>-1){
        scoring += 2 ;
        sprawdzRyzyko();
    }
});

console.log(scoring);

var sprawdzRyzyko = function () {
    if (scoring > 10){
        return true;  
    }     
}

// For Testing

var a = sprawdzRyzyko();
if (a){
    console.log("Hey it works!");
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szymondzumak/uJA39/)

You can set the `scoring` variable above 10 by sting the selects to 3 countries in `high_ryzyko_kraj` array.

Comment: if it is greater than 10 then what do you want to do? if you are expecting the `Hey it works!` to get logged it won't because the `if` condition is evaluated only once

Comment: Right, that might be a problem. How to listen for a change with 'if' inside the sprawdzRyzyko() function ?

Comment: Everything works perfectly : http://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/uJA39/6/  I just moved the test. As @ArunPJohny said, in your fiddle, it is performed only once

Comment: Your `if` runs when the page is loaded, not after the user changes the menus.

Comment: How to make it listen for a change as well  ? use change() inside the other function ?

Comment: do the opposite: instead of returning true invoke a function! Like: if (scoring > 10){
        console.log("Hey it works!"); 
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/uJA39/15/

```
var high_ryzyko_kraj = ['Polska', 'Afganistan', 'Ukraina'];
var less_ryzyko_kraj = ['Serbia', 'Egipt'];
var scoring = 0;
var sprawdzRyzyko = false;

$('#country, #country-bd, #country-wd').change(function(){
    if ($.inArray($(this).val(), high_ryzyko_kraj)>-1)
        scoring += 4;
    else if($.inArray($(this).val(), less_ryzyko_kraj)>-1)
        scoring += 2;
    if (scoring > 10){
        alert("Hey it works!");
        sprawdzRyzyko=true;
    }
});
```

I don't know your dynamics but are you sure that scoring shouldn't be set to 0 (zero) every time DDL changes (so inside change event handler)?

Hope this helps,

Have a nice day,

Alberto

Comment: thanks but still i got _ReferenceError: sprawdzRyzyko is not defined_
Need to that to be true.

Comment: I did. But it does not set the sprawdzRyzyko to true. when it's above 10

Comment: what do you mean? sprawdzRyzyko is a function, do you want it to become a boolean?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.    [Answer Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/uJA39/13/)

```
function sprawdzRyzyko() {
        if (scoring > 10) {
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks. But when my scoring is above 10 and i place sprawdzRyzyko() into console I get _ReferenceError: sprawdzRyzyko is not defined_ . Would love to see boolean true.

Comment: Did you not see the Fiddle answer?  It's testing the the function in the if statement.  Set the value to above 10 and the return value is true.  I don't know what else you are looking for.  Let me know what is not right in the answer Fiddle so that I can try to find the answer for you.

Comment: if(sprawdzRyzyko() == true){
    console.log("meoow");
}

Would love to hear the meooow sound :)